# mysql WHEN ? THEN ? with CONCAT

Tags: mysql

Mysql columns

```
 NumberRenamed | TypeOfBookkeepingRecord
 ---------------------------------------
     10        |    5
     11        |    5
```

query

```
UPDATE 2_1__paidused SET TypeOfBookkeepingRecord = CASE NumberRenamed
WHEN ? THEN CONCAT( TypeOfBookkeepingRecord, ? )
WHEN ? THEN CONCAT( TypeOfBookkeepingRecord, ? )
END;
```

Array

```
Array
(
[0] => 11
[1] => 4
[2] => 10
[3] => 4
)
```

Expect result like

```
 NumberRenamed | TypeOfBookkeepingRecord
 ---------------------------------------
     10        |    54
     11        |    54
```

Want to add number `4` in column `TypeOfBookkeepingRecord` to existing value/number

Query is incorrect. Got such error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''11' THEN CONCAT(
TypeOfBookkeepingRecord, '4' )WHEN '10' THEN CONCAT( TypeOfBoo' at line 1
```

Any ideas how to add value to existing value in mysql?

Query I generated in such way

1) before foreach `$updateQuery_paidused = '';`

2) inside foreach `$updateQuery_paidused .= 'WHEN ? THEN CONCAT( TypeOfBookkeepingRecord, ? )';` And inside foreach create array for `?`

3) after foreach `$sql_update_paidused = 'UPDATE 2_1__paidused SET TypeOfBookkeepingRecord = CASE NumberRenamed '. $updateQuery_paidused. 'END;';`

Comment: Well, how are you generating the later query?

Comment: @hjpotter92  Updated question. Added code how I generate the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax looks correct:

```
UPDATE 2_1__paidused
    SET TypeOfBookkeepingRecord = (CASE NumberRenamed
                                      WHEN ? THEN CONCAT( TypeOfBookkeepingRecord, ? )
                                      WHEN ? THEN CONCAT( TypeOfBookkeepingRecord, ? )
                                   END);
```

Could there be a transcription error?

However, I'm not sure it does what you want, because it will set other values to `NULL`.  This might be the query that you want:

```
UPDATE 2_1__paidused
    SET TypeOfBookkeepingRecord = CONCAT( TypeOfBookkeepingRecord, ? )
    WHERE NumberRenamed in (?, ?);
```

or:

```
UPDATE 2_1__paidused
    SET TypeOfBookkeepingRecord = (CASE NumberRenamed
                                      WHEN ? THEN CONCAT( TypeOfBookkeepingRecord, ? )
                                      WHEN ? THEN CONCAT( TypeOfBookkeepingRecord, ? )
                                      ELSE TypeOfBookkeepingRecord
                                   END);
```

Comment: @hjpotter92 . . . MySQL is pretty flexible about converting numbers and strings back and forth.  So, the following does work `select (case 10 when '10' then 1 else 0 end)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff At first sight strange behaviour, that i did not know before: CASE WHEN NumberRenamed = 10 THEN 4 does not mean that code would check only NumberRenamed with value 10; Appears that code goes throgh all values in column NumberRenamed and only where NumberRenamed is 10, the code sets TypeOfBookkeepingRecord 4. So before END need ELSE TypeOfBookkeepingRecord; it means if TypeOfBookkeepingRecord is not 10, then keeps existing value.

Comment: @user2118559 . . . You are learning SQL.  The `where` statement filters rows.  The `select` (or in this case the `set`) just does something to every selected row.  So, you do need an `else` or `where` clause to do what you want.